# How can I abstract multiple onChange events through a single React Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a simple inventory system that uses bi-directional data flow to render a form from state, the form can then be updated by the user and changes feed back into state. So far so good. Now I'd like to simplify my code as I have a bunch of different onChange Handlers -as each form input has a unique handler. How can I simplify my code and have a single onChange handler? I tried passing the state attribute that I wish to edit through the callBacks - but this doesn't work. However if I explicitly specify the state attribute I wish to edit then it works fine.

The top example works but the bottom example doesn't. What am I missing here?

```
MethodUpdateInventoryState (key, event, updatedValue) {

var fishState = this.state.fishes;
var eventTarget = "name";
fishState[key].name = updatedValue;
this.setState({fishes: fishState});
}




 MethodUpdateInventoryState (key, event, updatedValue) {

    var fishState = this.state.fishes;
    var eventTarget = "name";
    fishState[key].eventTarget = updatedValue;
    this.setState({fishes: fishState});
    }
```

Gracias!

Comment: `fishState[key][eventTarget] = updatedValue;` should work.  It is hard to comment on the approach with the information given though.

Comment: changing from fishState{key].eventTarget to  fishState{key][eventTarget] fixes the problem, Thanks! Though I don't understand why it works